# Is there a direct upload to YouTube with PS4?

Tags: ps4

So I am a sub account and I don't have a Facebook to download it to YouTube with. I don't have a capture card to use with my PS4 so I can't upload. I've checked the share stuff but couldn't find an upload to YouTube. Is there a thing I'm missing that you can upload to YouTube or do you need a capture card or Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, no, there is no direct link to YouTube.  However if you wish to upload a video in minutes to YouTube the process would be:

1. Ensure you have the video clip you wish to use displayed on the screen (this can be achieved by "Settings"-"System Storage"-"Videos" etc.) and also a flash drive inserted into the USB port.
2. Hit "Options" in your controller and a menu will slide in from the right-hand side.
3. Select "Copy to USB". Once the file is copied over, go to your PC or laptop and insert the flash drive.
4. Go to [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/), log in, select "Upload a video", select the video clip and upload it.

Warning: If the "Share" button is pressed it only stores the last half hour of gameplay, this is why I would recommend hitting the share button instantly after you decide to save it.

P.S. If you wish to edit the video before hand I would recommend using the PS4's ShareFactory to edit the video, this can be downloaded for free from the Playstore.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible now.

1. Connect your PSN account with your YouTube. Go to Settings > Sharing and Broadcasts > Link with Other Services > YouTube and enter your credentials there.
2. Record a video. Luckily, PS4 does everything for you automatically. It saves up to 60 minutes of your latest gameplay (this is configurable in Settings > Sharing and Broadcasts > Video Clip Settings).
3. You can use Share button on your controller to either save this recorded clip to Capture Gallery or upload it immediately (there will be additional steps to select video name, tags, privacy, see this [YouTube support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6105980?hl=en) for details). Later you can go to Capture Gallery, find your video and upload it using the same Share button.